# Read the filenames of group of files , make folders with specific file name(excluding extentions) than copy each file in their respective folder.

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, dos

Read the filenames of group of files , make folders with specific file name(excluding extentions) than copy each file in their respective folder. 
I had tried with this ,not working right

```
      @echo off
      for /F "tokens=1 delims =_" %%G in ('dir/b *.txt') do set testvariable=%%G
      md %testvariable%
      set "path=C:\Documents and Settings\USP\Desktop\"
      set "path2=%testvariable%"
      set "destpath=%path%%path2%"
      copy *.txt %destpath%
```

Comment: Do you realise that there's one space between `delims` and `=` in your `FOR` loop's options? Is the space also present in the actual script?

Answer (score 0):

[image]You cannot create a folder with same name as a file on the same location.

Comment: dear ,the above code is creating folders but the problem is that is not copying files to that folders.......

Comment: Dear, then you're not setting the folder name **exactly** as the file name, as you stated on your question. Did you try with _xcopy_ instead of _copy_?